# You use "CALL Proc_name()" as directly string, or use CommandType.StoredProcedure in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

**The question is:**

- When you call a Stored Procedure from MySQL to C# code, you place the
  string ["CALL Proc_name('param1', 'param2', 3)"] directly as a
  similar statement when inserting or deleting, like this:

  ```
  this.command= new MySqlCommand("CALL getAllNamesbyOld(5)", this.conn);
  this.command.ExecuteReader();
  ...
  ```
- Or you use
  MySqlCommand.CommandType for select Stored Procedure, like this:

  ```
  this.command = new MySqlCommand("getAllNamesbyOld", this.conn);
  this.command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  ```

Of course, in the first option, the parameters are directly in string; in the second option, you have to create the parameters with MySqlParameters and indicates it which parameters are IN or OUT direction.

**So which one to use ??**

Comment: to a large extent most people would argue the first one parameters should be used too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `CommandType.StoredProcedure` is faster

When using `CommandType.StoredProcedure` you will be the one to parameterize it and will be saving database some work.

When using the first option, MySQL will do the parameterization.